# What's the best way to shorten/transform a string

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0

I have several users and I would like to generate a referral url for each of them, but I don't think it would be nice to have something like

```
http://domain.com/myusername
```

I would prefer to buy myself a shorten domain and transfor that `myusername`into something smaller, **but not generated using the database** so it would be easy to manage and no need to have a special table for this.

kinda like Dropbox does, as my referral is: http://db.tt/jnYosez

is there a simple way to change between a string into a short string and vice versa ... or I can always use the User ID if I'm force to use numeric ... maybe converting to other number base ?

Any idea is mostly appreciated :)

Comment: So you are trying to build a url-shortener? Hmmm.. we never can have enough of these, can we?

Comment: @Mayank No, I'm not, just wanna give a different name instead of the `username`, that's it ... it I wanted a C# ShortUrl Solution, I would go here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/shorturl-dotnet/

Comment: What's wrong with the length? Won't the actual link be disguised by the link text anyway?

Comment: Why do you think that `myusername` is less nice than some random generated string? Anyway, you don't need another table for it, just add that random generated value to the users table as a column

Comment: @Victor Hurdugaci I would probably go that way as it turns out it's much easier to remember as well :-/ dang, sometimes we developers tend to complicate the simple things :o(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it inhouse without using a database. It's because the names are short and therefore it's likely that a name have been used before.

You need to generate a name (using randomness or an algorithm), check if it exists and then store it in the db.

### Update

Here is a solution:

```
    public class NumberConverter
    {
        public const string HEX = "0123456789abcdef";
        public const string Bigger = "0123456789abcdefghihjklmnopqrstuvqyz";
        private int _numericBase;
        private string _base;

        public NumberConverter(string numberBase)
        {
            _base = numberBase;
            _numericBase = numberBase.Length;
        }

        public string ToString(int number)
        {
            var remainder = number % _numericBase;
            var div = number / _numericBase;
            string tmp = "";
            while (div > 0)
            {
                tmp = _base[remainder] + tmp;

                remainder = div % _numericBase;
                div = div / _numericBase;
            }
            tmp = _base[remainder] + tmp;

            return tmp;
        }

        public int ToNumber(string numberString)
        {
            int index = numberString.Length - 1;
            int value = 0;
            int power = 0;
            while (index >= 0)
            {
                char currentChar = numberString[index];
                var currentValue = _base.IndexOf(currentChar);
                value += currentValue * (int)Math.Pow(_numericBase, power);
                power++;
                --index;
            }

            return value;
        }
    }



    public static void Main()
    {
        var converter = new NumberConverter(NumberConverter.Bigger);
        int userId = 755757;
        var numberString = converter.ToString(userId); // prints g759
        var value = converter.ToNumber(numberString);
    }
```

You can shorten the numbers even more by adding more that are allowed in uris.

Theres probably a more efficient way to do it. Bitwise operations isn't really my area.

### Update 2

> Characters that are allowed in a URI but do not have a reserved purpose are called unreserved.  These include uppercase and lowercase letters, decimal digits, hyphen, period, underscore, and tilde.

```
  unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
```

Which means that you can use those to shorten the url (unless your web server is using them for something else)

Comment: Well, that's not particulary right as I can always encode the `UserId` or the `Username` and upon decoding it it will always be `UserId: 123` or `Username: balexandre`. I could as well convert the `UserId` into Base16 for example...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [bit.ly](http://bit.ly/) links, they provide [an API](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation).

Comment: I own the Pro account, I never thought about using them for this ... maybe it's not a bad idea, though ... would love to do something "in-house".